# How to dynamically update theme of my Ionic app based on a button click event?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to dynamically change button colors in my ionic app based on a button click.

Here is my Typescript:

```
  renderer: Renderer2;

  constructor(private rendererFactory: RendererFactory2, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
    this.renderer = this.rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
  }

  enableDark(): void {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.document.body, 'dark-theme');
  }

  enableLight(): void {
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.document.body, 'dark-theme');
  }
```

And here is my `app.component.scss`:

```
:root {
    .dark-theme {
      --ion-color-primary: #eb4b58;
  --ion-color-primary-rgb: 235, 75, 88;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --ion-color-primary-shade: #cd424d;
  --ion-color-primary-tint: #ed5d69;
    }
}
```

When I click on the button, the class is being added / removed from the body element as expected, but the button color isn't changing.

Can someone please tell me what is the issue with my code, & how I can resolve it?